# Получение ViewBag после IView.Render

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-mvc

Есть функция "отрисовки" View'а в строку:

```
protected virtual string RenderViewToString(string viewName, object model)
{
    ViewData.Model = model;

    if (viewName == null)
        viewName = ControllerContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action");

    using (var sw = new StringWriter())
    {
        var viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(ControllerContext, viewName);
        var viewContext = new ViewContext(ControllerContext, viewResult.View, ViewData, TempData, sw);

        viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);
        viewResult.ViewEngine.ReleaseView(ControllerContext, viewResult.View);
        return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
    }
}
```

в View'е происходит установка значений **ViewBag**:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = Locale.Current[...];
 }
```

Как получить обновленный **ViewBag** после `IView.Render()` ?

Answer (score 1):

Метод `RenderView` копирует `ViewData` себе внутрь - и универсальными методами его обратно уже не достать. Если есть доступ к вызываемой вьюхе, можно сделать одно из этих действий:

1. Использовать не `ViewBag`, а `ViewContext.ViewBag`.
2. Положить в `ViewBag` какой-нибудь объект, и менять уже его свойство `Title`. Назвать как-нибудь вроде `Output`.

Пример:

```
viewContext.ViewBag.Output = new OutputParametersModel();
viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);
```

ну и в виде

```
@{
    ViewBag.Output.Title = Locale.Current[...];
}
```

Как частный случай второго случая, в `ViewBag` можно засунуть его самого, чтобы не создавать лишних моделей:

```
viewContext.ViewBag.Output = viewContext.ViewBag;
viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);
```

и дальше так же.

Answer (score 0):

ViewBag только для передачи данных вьюхе, от вьюхи контроллеру лучше данные передавать через роутинг/параметры запроса

Но если сильно хочется, то можете использовать TempData. Использовать можно как ViewData, но есть одна особенность - данные сохраняются до следующего запроса и уходят после прочтения

Рекомендую для ознакомления [Passing Data in an ASP.NET MVC Application](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/dd394711(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: TempData использует сессию, а у сессии есть очень неприятные негативные эффекты.